# Java: Adding a parallel process and simple write to file

Tags: java

I'm helping a grade 11 student with her intro to java project. It's a simple quiz game I'm familiar with scripting and stuff but I'm not exactly sure how to add a second thread/process/not sure what the proper name is in java so that I can have a countdown timer running while waiting for user input. Also, I want to write a highscore to a textfile (with name), is there a super straightforward way of doing that?

I'm looking for the simplest approach so that I can easily explain it to her?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
new Thread ( new Runnable()
{
      public void run()
      {
                 // Place your code here
      }
}).start();
```